# Removing DFP 'X' button at top right corner of Banner

Tags: wordpress, google-dfp

I have two banners on my WordPress site which is link to DFP. The banner on top have a 'X' button and the one at the bottom does not have. I'm not sure why one has it and one doesn't have it.

[Screenshot of Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBUdr.png)

I want to remove the 'X' button on the banner. I tried using CSS to change the z-index, opacity and the visibility using custom CSS on WordPress but it is still not working. Anybody know any method to hide the button? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In DFP : Go to Admin > Global settings > untick the box 'mute this ad'